# ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

This error appears when i try load model with my custom layer.

```
model = load_model('my_model.h5', custom_objects={'MyLayer': MyLayer})
```

Im trying to visualize what is happening in my custom keras layer. Im working with images of BrainMRI and trying just to flip them in layer.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs, name = 'MyLayer', **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs


    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                  shape=(input_shape[1], self.num_outputs),
                                  initializer='normal', trainable=True)

        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        flipped = K.reverse(inputs,axes=0)
        return flipped

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

    def get_config(self):
        base = super(MyLayer, self).get_config()
        base['num_outputs'] = self.num_outputs
        return dict(list(base.items()))
```

I tried reinstall keras as some thread was recommending but nothing happens

Comment: You should include the full traceback as errors in isolation do not make any sense

Comment: Im sorry for that but eventually i found problem with the type of saved model and loading. I mean if I saved weights and then load model with weights.hdf5 file its working. Anyway thx for ur time

Comment: I encountered the same error. Can you tell me how did you solve this issue? @RomanVarga

Comment: @AstraUvarova-Saturn'sstar Hi I think after I changed the type of saving model file from h5 to hdf5 it solved the problem :) have a nice day